# I want to give an effect of zoom out from 200% to 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints, jquery-transit

I'm using waypoints and jquery transit. I'm able to achieve the effect of zoom out from 200% to 100%. But for that i have to write all my css to default of 200% and then my jquery transit  ake it scale 0.5 to normal size.

I mean is there a smart way to do it.

this is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/eJ2Mw/1/

```
.fortyone-mil {
font: bold 72px/72px"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #1374a6;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
position:relative;
top:115px;
opacity:1;
}
```

you can see the text between the circle getting zoomed out

Comment: `scale` / `transform` is a smart way to do it. Do you have any issues in your implementation ?

Comment: @jashwant: my problem is that to scale out i have to make all css in 200% and then scale down to 100%. I want to make normal size css and whichever item i wanna scale out just onload make them 200%. Am i making sense to you or I am unclear

Comment: Then just code with normal css and scale to 200% on page load with transit. Or you can have a css class with `transform`, which you can add to elements which you want to scale.

Comment: that is what I am struggling to do. How to scale css to 200% or nomal onload

Comment: You can add a css `transform: scale(2, 2)` to transform those elements.

Comment: I'm confused can you show me a small fiddle if thats not a pain

Comment: I tried giving a delay like this $(".fortyone-mil").transition({ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }, 500, 'in').delay( 2000 );  But its not working am i doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use css3 transform to have zoom out / zoom in functionality.

**jQuery**

```
$(".fortyone-mil").transition({
  opacity: 1,
  scale: 1
}, 500, 'in');
```

**CSS:**

```
.fortyone-mil {
 -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
      transform: scale(2);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ2Mw/3/)

Comment: dude why i didn't think about that. you are a star. Thanks a lot

Comment: is there a way where I can delay for the next animation?

Comment: You can use jquery's `delay()` function for elements in queue. Or you may use `setTimeout`. Please mark the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: i have already marked your solution as right one i gave it +1. you can see

Comment: +1 is for upvoting. You need to mark it as answer. Click on the 'right' tick mark to approve it as answer ;)

Comment: i have done that too and also i managed to do the delay. What is better delay or settimeout?